# Use Renderer on VirtualColumn in Admin Grid

Tags: magento

On previous works, I've overrided the Order grid in the Magento Admin, to display others data. So I've create a module to do so. I  wrote the new block and reported the overriding in the config.xml :

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <sales_order_grid>
                 Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
            </sales_order_grid>
       </rewrite>
   </adminhtml>
</block>
```

After that I've created a new module to get and save new data. I want now to display them on the grid. These data come from a custom table and are not already used in the grid. I've also to use a renderer to display them.

I don't want to make these two modules dependent of each other, the new data have to be displayed on the overrided grid as on the default one. So I want (if it's possible) to avoid an other overriding of the first module by the second one.

By searching on the Internet, I found this interesting article : http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html

```
$resource->addVirtualGridColumn(
    'customer_telephone',
    'sales/order_address',
    array('billing_address_id' => 'entity_id'),
    'telephone'
);
```

This approach is perfect for me : if the first module is disabled, the data of the second one are still displayed on the default grid, and if the second module is disabled, the grid is still overrided.

It could have been perfect, but it seems you can't use a renderer by using the addVirtualGridColumn method.

So my question is : Is there a way to use renderer on virtual column ? And if not, is there still a way to elegantly add a "rendered" column without overriding the grid ?

Hope I've been clear in the explanation of my issue and hope there's a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML:

```
<add_order_grid_column_handle>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
       <action method="addColumnAfter">
         <columnId>customer_telephone</columnId>
         <arguments module="" translate="header">
            <header>Customer telephone</header>
            <index>custom_telephone</index>
            <type>tex</type>
            <sortable>true</sortable>
            <renderer>YOUR_CUSTOM_RENDERER_CLASS</renderer>
          </arguments>
          <after>....</after>
        </action>
    </reference>
</add_order_grid_column_handle>
```